# Is there a way to show the directory your current document is located in Libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I'm trying to figure out where the document I'm working on is located on the hard drive. Is there a command that opens the containing folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the information you are looking for in the document properties (`File` -> `Properties`). In the `General` tab, you will find the location, as well as the file name and other information:

[image: Document Properties]

This was verified for a Writer document in LibreOffice 6.0.6.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.1. The dialogues may be slightly different on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what I'm looking for, but if you click File > Save as... the save dialog will open in the last place this document was saved.

Comment: On Ubuntu, `File` -> `Properties` -> `General` tab shows the name and location of the current document.

Comment: That would make a great answer!